# Need solution to highlight words which are not following silent e rule

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

am endeavoring to highlight a word upon clicking that does not adhere to the exception of the silent 'e' rule. Despite multiple attempts with various regex patterns, I consistently encounter the same outcome.

```
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, ImageBackground,StatusBar,Image,Dimensions, TouchableOpacity,ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React,{useState,useContext} from 'react'
import style from '../theme/style'
import themeContext from '../theme/themeContex';
import { Colors } from '../theme/color';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import { AppBar,HStack, IconButton  } from '@react-native-material/core';
// import { Avatar } from 'react-native-paper';
import Height from './Height';
import {Avatar} from 'react-native-elements';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { color } from 'react-native-elements/dist/helpers';
import BackButton from './Componants/BackButton';
import Header from './Componants/Header';


const width =Dimensions.get('screen').width
const height = Dimensions.get('screen').height
// Regex pattern to determine if a word follows the silent "e" rule
// Regex pattern to determine if a word follows the silent "e" rule
const regex = /(?:[^aeiouy]|y$|a(?!i)|e(?!a)|(ia)|(ei)|(ie)|(eu)|(ui))$/;

const exceptions = [
  "love", "move", "come", "rule", "give", "above", "done", "bone", "some",
  "gate", "whole", "horse", "house", "mouse", "once",
];
// const regex = /[^aeiou]e(?=[a-z])/;



export default function RuleExceptions() {

  const theme = useContext(themeContext);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false)


  const [clickedWords, setClickedWords] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (word) => {
    // Check if the word is an exception based on the regex pattern and exception list
    const isException = !regex.test(word) && exceptions.includes(word); // Correct condition
  
    // Update the clickedWords state with the clicked word and its exception status
    if (clickedWords.find(w => w.word === word)) {
      // Remove the word from the list if it's already clicked
      setClickedWords(clickedWords.filter(w => w.word !== word));
    } else {
      // Add the word to the list with its exception status
      setClickedWords([...clickedWords, { word, isException }]);
    }
  };

  const words = [
    'Have', 'Like', 'Love', 'Side', 'Done', 'Mute', 'Come', 'Rule',
    'Gate', 'Above', 'Bake', 'Bike', 'Pole', 'Flute', 'Here', 'Some'
  ];

  console.log("Regex pattern:", regex);
  console.log("Exceptions:", exceptions);
  console.log("Current clickedWords:", clickedWords);

    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, paddingTop:25}}>
             
      

      <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/image/read.png')}
      style={{flex:1}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor={"#C2EEFF"} translucent={true}/>
          <Header />
         
            <View style={{ paddingHorizontal:20,}}>
              <Text style={{fontFamily:'BADABB', fontSize:21, color:'#E51F5C', textAlign:'center', width:'100%', letterSpacing:1, lineHeight:21,}}>Silent E – Rule Exceptions!</Text>
              {/* <Text style={{fontFamily:'BADABB', fontSize:21, color:'#E51F5C', textAlign:'center', width:'100%', letterSpacing:1, lineHeight:21, marginBottom:15,}}>Aa and Ee Vowel Sounds</Text> */}
              <Text style={{fontFamily:'Cheesecake', fontSize:18, color:'#000', textAlign:'center', width:'100%', letterSpacing:1, marginTop:10, lineHeight:20,}}>Highlight the words where Silent E does NOT follow the rule! </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{paddingHorizontal:20, marginTop:20,}}>
              <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap', width:'100%', borderWidth:2, borderColor:'#0E73BB'}}>
                    {words.map((word, index) => (
                    <View key={index} style={{ width: '25%', borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#0E73BB', borderBottomWidth: 2 }}>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleClick(word)}>
                        <Text style={{
                          paddingVertical: 5,
                          fontWeight: '600',
                          fontFamily: 'Cheesecake',
                          fontSize: 18,
                          textAlign: 'center',
                          backgroundColor: clickedWords.find(w => w.word === word)?.isException ? 'green' : 'transparent',
                          color: '#1C3014',
                        }}>{word}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                  ))}
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{marginTop:20,}}>
              <Text style={{fontFamily:'BADABB', fontSize:18, color:'#E51F5C', textAlign:'center', width:'100%', letterSpacing:1, lineHeight:21,}}>REMEMBER: Not all words will follow this rule. </Text>
              <Text style={{fontFamily:'BADABB', fontSize:18, color:'#E51F5C', textAlign:'center', width:'100%', letterSpacing:1, lineHeight:21,}}>When you get to a silent E word, try to sound it out using BOTH vowel sounds to see what would make sense </Text>
            </View>
          
        <BackButton style={{width:'100%',}}/>
       </ImageBackground>
            
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

below is the outcome of the above code

`Current clickedWords: [{"isException": false, "word": "Have"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Done"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Gate"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Pole"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Flute"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Above"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Mute"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Like"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Love"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Come"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Bake"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Here"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Some"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Bike"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Rule"}, {"isException": false, "word": "Side"}]`

I want the above code to highlight the word which is not following the rule

**Silent E Rule**

The silent 'e' is an 'e' at the end of the word that's not pronounced. In a short vowel sound, a vowel is typically by itself, while a long vowel sound involves the addition of a silent 'e' where the resulting words sound just like the vowel's name.

Comment: For the unwashed who do not know what the "silent 'e' rule" is, you might want to add that explanation to your question.

Comment: @Pointy i have added the explanation, thanks for advise.

Comment: I am sorry, but your explanation of the 'Silent "e" rule' makes little sense. By words that follow the silent "e" rule do mean the words that end with silent "-e" making the preceding written syllable formally open, and therefore, making the last pronounced vowel sound [eɪ] for a, [iː] for e, [aɪ] for i and y, [əʊ] for o and [juː] for u?